# To create a trigger that if I insert a row in child table with null foreign key ,It inserts a new row in parent table with that criteria and new id

Tags: mysql, triggers, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1452

This is factors table:

```
CREATE TABLE `factors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price_sum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

And this one is subfactors table:

```
CREATE TABLE `subfactors` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `factor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY subfactors(`factor_id`) REFERENCES factors(`id`))
```

I've tried this query but it says that I can't insert a row into a child table:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger AFTER INSERT
ON subfactors FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.factor_id=NULL THEN 
        INSERT INTO factor(id,price_sum) 
        VALUES(NEW.factor_id,NEW.price);
    END IF;
END //
```

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: I don't believe you. There is **NO** any FOREIGN KEY definition in shown code, so you cannot receive an error relative to non-existent entity.

Comment: I edited it check it now

Comment: FOREIGN KEY `factor_id` (`factor_id`) is not valid you need to include the referenced table and referenced table column..

Comment: And you seem to have misunderstood how FKs work the parent has to exist before the child and this check is carried out BEFORE the trigger fired so you cannot create a parent from a child in a trigger.

Comment: What now? I just edited the fk

Comment: BTW =null should be is null.